# getting rid of unchecked assignment

Tags: java, spring

I have the following piece of code

```
1. final List<Map<String, Object>> maps = ...
2. final Map<String, Object>[] arrMaps = maps.toArray(new Map[maps.size()]);
3. getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate().batchUpdate(..., arrMaps);
```

On line 3 I get an `Unchecked assignement`. How can I get rid of it?

I do not want to suppress the warning and I can't figure out how to fix it. If a try to cast or convert something, the warning appears somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a way to get rid of that unchecked exception by playing with types and casts. Instead I used `MapSqlParameterSource[]` as a source of data for my `batchUpdate`.